# Are case-studies an effective way of getting efficiency-focused team members to be willing to trade some efficiency for quality?

Tags: scrum, efficiency, quality

- Firstly, this does not suggest that efficiency and quality are in conflict... only that some methods prioritize them differently.
- Secondly, this is not a question of whether you agree with Scrum practice or not.

An expressed goal of Scrum is to create high quality increments of a deliverable product. This does not exclude that it might be done efficiently, but efficiency is not the focus.

Most programmers want to both deliver quality products **and** be efficient about it. Scrum's requirement to add product backlog items to a sprint backlog from the top of the prioritized list only... will often result in resistance from programmers, such as:

> "But it will be more efficient if we add these other two items, from further down the priority list, to this sprint".

Perhaps the prioritization of the product backlog items could have been influenced differently by the Scrum Master, while working with the Product Owner. Such could be addressed in the next product backlog refinement session.

Setting aside such issues, are case-studies (of other teams' effective uses of Scrum) an effective way of swaying reluctant team members? (particularly on the issue of efficiency) Or, is there something better than case-studies?

Comment: Are you the boss?

Comment: "Boss" or not, while a factor, is not relevant to this question. It is not about expressing authority, but rather about convincing someone to actually shift their own "belief".

Comment: It can't be done, unless management is firmly committed to the idea of sacrificing efficiency (read "results") for higher quality (I doubt that they are), and the team members can see that following management's purview will be in their best interests.  *It's not about case studies, it's what incentives management provides to their people.*

Comment: The fact that Scrum **is being used** implies that management is committed. You can't just go ahead and use Scrum without management having agreed. Furthermore, team members are not solely motivated by the authority of management.

Comment: `You can't just go ahead and use Scrum without management having agreed.` --Many companies do try.

Comment: Recommended reading: **[How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6629/22815)**

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Yes... sad, but true.

Comment: @Snowman, That is good recommended reading. Here, however, the issue appears to be more about "convincing" rather than "explaining". (closely related, admittedly) The aforementioned team members do **understand** scrum. They don't so much require **explaining** of scrum.

Comment: @David in this context they are the same thing. "How do I explain why person X needs to do Y _my_ way?"

Comment: @Snowman, Thanks for your effort to improve my question. With regard to your last edit, however, the following seems applicable: [What should the standard spelling be - British or US?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us)

Comment: @David I went to fix the spelling in the title when a word in the body came up with a red squiggly. Given the poor spelling of many programmers who post here, I was not even thinking locale (en-US v. en-GB).

Comment: @Snowman, FYI, the word changed in the title was also a British vs US variant, but I don't care enough to change it back. I would be perfectly happy if my spell checker would recogni**z**e when I'm in SE and use US English instead.

Comment: Well, if they care about efficiency, convince them that your way is more efficient, or that their criteria for deciding what is the most efficient (or what needs to be optimized) need adjustment. How to do that? Beats me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Setting aside such issues, are case-studies (of other teams' effective uses of Scrum) an effective way of swaying reluctant team members? (particularly on the issue of efficiency) Or, is there something better than case-studies?

Case studies really are a poor substitute to general experience and even if people read them, it likely won't make any big difference.

Your problem is one of ulterior goals.  A Scrum team is forward thinking only in terms of getting items into the backlog that need to be worked on.  They are also forward thinking in "Sprint Zero" mode where they are planning the project overall, high level design and environment buildouts.  That is it.

*Everything else should be a short term goal for the scrum team, completing the next sprint to product owner acceptance.*

If your team members are thinking about later rework then they are right to bring it up as a concern during Sprint Planning, but the decision to bring it into the sprint rests solely on the Product Owner.  Rework is only a concern when the Product Owner considers it to be a problem but he/she should be aware of the technical implications of what she is committing the team to.

So how should you convince the team?

You need to get everybody on the team aligned with the same goal in mind.  Report potential technical issues and risks, and spike when you don't have enough information, but ultimately, when you commit to a story your feelings should be left at the door and you should do it regardless of the down stream impacts.  The team just needs to be clear about how much effort will be expended to do this and if it is realistic in terms of the allocated sprint time.

**If developers are concerned about having to write a bunch of code that will be thrown away later then they are not aligned.**

The goal is quickly delivering business value NOW, not preventing future rework.  It is not about them and their worries about refactoring and future workload, get them to abandon these goals by stressing the importance of Minimum Viable Product and quickly delivering business value.

Answer (score 1):

There is something better. It is called 'authority'. Product owner decides what goes first and what goes after.

However, it's expected from developers to communicate to product owner that some things might be more efficient doing one way or another.

That being said, authority is still the product owner, and based on the input from developers, product owner has to decide whether to stick to his plan or alter the plan a bit.

**Professional developer is the one who informs the product owner of possible optimizations**, but not the one who refuses to do something because "he believes so".

Comment: Are you saying that exercising authority is a more effective way of actually convincing team members to willingly rebalance the quality vs efficiency question in their minds, @Alexus?

Comment: I am saying you shouldn't need to convince a developer anything. Developer is hired to do the job and customer is the business unit in this case. If business unit decides to sacrifice quality and/or efficiency for other needs, developer does so without questions. And authority is to make it clear to the developer. I am not saying developers are slaves, I am however saying that developers often don't consider business needs at all. I am a developer myself by the way and I have been through that cycle.

Comment: Then, what you have provided is an answer to a different question. You are saying that the team members' **do not need to be convinced of anything**. The question, however, was about **how to convince the team members**.

Comment: My answer identifies and covers alternative solution to your problem, at least how I see it.

Comment: The answer does not necessarily have to directly address the question if the question demonstrates a very clear problem and the answer provides a good faith and quality attempt to provide an answer to the problem. If you think the answer is off base however then feel free to downvote answers you don't like.